# Keyboard not getting displayed on iphone X

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have created a new blank project in ionic v1 using the below command

1. ionic start MyApp --type ionic1
2. ionic build
3. ionic cordova platform add ios

I have below configuration in my mac

- Ionic cli: 4.5.0
- cordova : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
- xcode: 10.1

In my existing project I am facing one issue, I am unable to open the keyboard from iphone x while trying to write some text in a textbox.
So tried to replicate the same in a new ionic v1 project and there also it is not working.

Added the below code in index.html inside `<ion-content>` tag.

```
<div style="padding: 20px;">
  <label class="input-label" for="username">Username</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your username" id="username-signin">    
</div>
```

Then I have opened the project in xcode.  Run the app in simulator iphone x.
When I click on the textbox I am not able to see the keyboard but if I run the application in simulator iphone 6s I am able to see the keyboard.

Attaching the screen shot of the same

[image]

Comment: You can toggle simulator keyboard by pressing cmd+k/cmd+shift+k

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard#usage

Comment: The device simulator can be configured to simulate a connected bluetooth keyboard. If that is the case, it won't show the keyboard on screen. As @TejaNandamuri already pointed out, check the simulator menu: Hardware / Keyboard / Connect Hardware Keyboard